# Creating sequence in Oracle Programmatically using JPA

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in my Spring boot project to handle DB stuff.

I want to create a sequence in Oracle programmatically.
I have seen many solution which create sequence using raw query but i want to create a sequence from the code. Is there anything i can do using JPA.

I also want to get this sequence number and return it to the caller.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to allow Hibernate (one of the JPA implementations available in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) create DDL statements, so in *application.properties*:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

**Note that it is not recommended for production.**

Next, annotate your entity in following way:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_generator", sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE",  allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    //...
}
```

Once your application will start, hibernate based on your `ddl-auto` configuration will  create the sequence for you:

*Hibernate: create sequence MY_SEQUENCE start with 1 increment by  1*

You can read more about `ddl-auto`configurations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do).